# SSIS Dataflow task- CSv to sql table an extra comma in last column

Tags: ssis

I am importing a csv to a sql table using SSIS dataflow task, my problem is a Comma(,) is saving in last column of the table appending the value in the column. I don't see any comma in CSV file though.
Given Text Delimiter as ". But it is not solving the problem. Can someone help me with this issue

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Open up the .csv file in a notepad editor (right click .csv file and say open with) and pick NotePad++ is the best one.  then you can see all characters you may not see if you open it by double clicking (probably opens in Excel).  This should show you all characters you may be missing.

Answer (score 0):

1. Please open csv file with Notepad to see if the data has  ***delimiter*** or ***text qualifier*** .
2. Please choose proper ***delimiter*** or ***qualifier*** in Flat File Connection Manager.

Useful pictures:

[OpenWithNotepad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Infpl.jpg)

[Text Qualifier](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mFMMp.jpg)

[Delimiter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5uI3j.jpg)